# Problems to see the matrix correctly when viewing it in html output with R

Tags: r, mathjax

When I am in the r markdown console, the matrix looks fine but when I transform it to html output I get the r code.

````
class: title-slide, center, middle
background-image: url(https://us.123rf.com/450wm/giddavr/giddavr1405/giddavr140500043/28389662-en-diagonal-graduado-resumen-antecedentes-sin-forma-difusa-pink.jpg?ver=6)
background-size: cover

# EXERCISE 12

## Ana

### University
`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %e, %Y')`

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(leaps)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(xaringanthemer)
library(xaringanExtra)
download.file(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css",
  "animate.css"
)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,message = F,warning = F)
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
library(ISLR)
library(xaringanthemer)
library(xaringanExtra)
library(tidyverse)
style_solarized_light(
  text_bold_color = "#000000",
  header_color = "#D65DB1",
  inverse_text_color = "#ffffff",
  background_color = "#FBEAFF",
  code_highlight_color = "#D65DB1",
  text_color = "#000000"
)
```
class: middle, center, animated, fadeIn

# STATEMENT

 This problem is a continuation of the previous exercise. In a toy example with p=100, show that estimates of the multiple linear regression coefficients can be approximated by repeatedly performing simple linear regression in a backfitting procedure. How many backfitting iterations are needed to get a "good" approximation to the estimates of the multiple regression coefficients? Create a graph to justify your answer.

---
title: "Exercise 12"
subtitle: "statistics"
author: "Ana"
institute: "Universisity"
date: "27/03/2023"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: 
      - xaringan-themer.css
      - xaringan-themer.css
      - "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css"
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    seal: false
---

---
class: middle, animated, bounceInRight
````

I display the first 20 × 6 entries of the beta_matrix, which now has the form:

where $\hat{β}_{j(k)}$ es la estimación de $β_j$ en la iteración k.

```
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{β}_{0(1)} & \hat{β}_{1(1)} & \cdots & \hat{β}_{100(1)}\\
\hat{β}_{0(2)} & \ddots &  & \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \\
\hat{β}_{0(50)} &  &  & \hat{β}_{100(50)}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
```

What should I do? Thanks. I see that the matrix appears fine in the r markdown view but when I knit into html it doe´sn appear well.

Comment: Could you please share your rmarkdown code? Including YAML header

Answer (score 0):

The `pmatrix` environment is in the LaTeX package `amsmath`, so it's not available to the html renderer.  You could use an array like:

```
$$\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\hat{\beta}_{0(1)} & \hat{\beta}_{1(1)} & \cdots & \hat{\beta}_{100(1)}\\
\hat{\beta}_{0(2)} & \ddots &  & \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \\
\hat{\beta}_{0(50)} &  &  & \hat{\beta}_{100(50)}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}$$
```

which produces a similar kind of output and renders appropriately in html.

[image]